# Typescript : update value from input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I have a list of restaurants made by *ngFor. I can click on the one I wanna change which make it an input field with the label text in it.

What I want to do do is to get the text value of the input field and update the label value with it when I click a button.

You'll understand better with the code :

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let restaurant of event.restaurants; let index = index">
            <div class="col-xs-5" (click)="update=true" off-click="update=false">
                <input *ngIf="update" type="text" name="champ" value="{{restaurant.name}}" placeholder="{{restaurant.name}}"/>
                <a *ngIf="!update">{{restaurant.name}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                {{restaurant.category.description}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="!update" (click)="DelRestaurant(index)">{{'EVENT_RESTAURANT_REMOVE' | translate}}</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="update" (click)="UpdateRestaurant(index)">Modifier</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

With `UpdateRestaurant(index)`, I want to get the input value and change `{{restaurant.name}}`

If you could help me that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With UpdateRestaurant(index), I want to get the input value and change
>   {{restaurant.name}}

I'm not 100% sure with Angular2, however with Angular for repeated entries you could pass in the object associated with the section.

Which means you can pass the restaurant object..

```
(click)="UpdateRestaurant(restaurant)"
```

With the object loaded changing the "name" on the object will change the view.